# Sonicwall firewall router dhcp server stops working intermittently

Tags: router, dhcp-server, sonicwall

I just bought a Sonicwall SOHO which is the new model that replace TZ105, TZ 205 series.

The network stops working intermittently. The whole network is down after every 30~70 minutes of uptime, no Internet, cannot access the router admin panel. I have to hard restart the router to access it or get the internet back online. I found it could be caused by the DHCP server of the router. When the network is down, the server stops assigning any IP addresses.

Can anyone give me some clue what can cause this ? Any resolution that I can apply ? I have been dealing with this whole day, I am hoping someone can give me some direction. Thanks a lot.

Update: After the router is down, I tried to set up IP address manually and ping the router. The ping return "destination host unreachable".

Comment: The firewall not assigning ip addresses should have no bearing on clients that have an existing ip address lease. Based on your update I'd say the firewall is defective. Is it running the latest firmware/software?

Comment: joeqwerty, it is not running latest firmware. I just upgraded the latest firmware. I hope this solve the issue after 12 hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: The firewall %CPU is surelly at 100% and thus log nothing and serve nothing, as it dont ping either. Do you can use a small soho router like a linksys to rule out ? As the packet inspection of those small box can get killed on big WAN's link, while small router like a linksys do nothing of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from Spiceworks community and fixed this issue. It is because the previous firmware were not stable. The issue was resolved after I updated it to the latest firmware.

If you are interested, you may refer to the post [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1616284-sonicwall-soho-firewall-router-dhcp-server-stops-working-intermittently?page=1#entry-5824720).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a TZ200 lately. I asked Sonicwall's support about that and the problem was tracked down to a corrupted configuration. I had to factory reset the device and reconfigure it **without** using the backupped settig files.

However, before doing that, try updating the firmware to the latest version (but in my case it was of no help).

If nothing seems to help, you should connect to the firewall console port (which should be functional even if the device itself crashes) and capture the logs. Then forward them to Sonicwall's support.

Comment: Hi, shodanshok. I did try to restore the router to factory default and reconfigure it with least services. It doesn't solve my issue. I just upgraded my firmware to latest about an hour ago. I hope it's the firmware bug which caused all these.